# select box is not working on android 2.3 using phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova, iscroll

Selecting elements in html page is behaving weird on android 2.3.5 version mobiles.I implemented i-scroll on page which contains three drop downs.When i select last drop down element,first element values are populating.I came to known that the elements overlay comes down because of i-scroll.Give me suggestions on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding this code to your javascript (where selectBoxID is the ID of your select box)

```
var Select = document.getElementById('selectBoxID');
    Select.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }, false);
```

Hope this helps!